# Unix: Print extra column of values to file

Tags: seq

I have a .txt file (`new_file.txt`) with a column of values (200). I need to print another column beside it, with values 0,1/200,2/200.....1. How should I do this? I am new to this, so any suggestions will be great!

I know that `seq 0 0.005 1 >new_file.txt` will print it into the file, but it overwrites the values already present. I want to add these numbers as another column beside the values already present in the file.

The input is like:

```
2.41
2.56
```

etc. in a column. I need it to look like

```
2.41 0
2.56 0.005
```

etc. in a column. I need to have a tab in between.

Comment: use `paste` or `pr` command... suggest to show small sample (say 5 lines) for input and how the output should look after column addition.. should it be added with space/tab/etc in between or without any separation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `seq` and `paste`:

```
seq 0 0.005 1 | paste newfile.txt - > newerfile.txt
```

With `awk`

```
awk '{$2 = 0.005*(NR-1)} 1' OFS='\t' newfile.txt > newerfile.txt
```

Depending on your version of `awk`, you may be able to modify `newfile.txt` in place.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, `paste` is the best option to do what you want.

```
 paste new_file.txt <sequence file>
```

If you want to generate sequence at run time

```
seq 0 0.005 1 | paste new_file.txt /dev/stdin
```

Example (for 5 records in `new_file.txt`)

```
~$ seq 0 0.005 0.020 | paste new_file.txt /dev/stdin
2.41    0.000
2.56    0.005
2.71    0.010
2.86    0.015
3.01    0.020
```

Note: If any of the file/command have extra rows in it, then corresponding rows in output would be blank. So make sure that both files have same number of row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `GNU dc` as follows:

```
< new_file.txt tr -- - _ | dc -e "[q]sq [?z1=qrd1<qrn32anp0.005+dd=?]s? 0l?x"
```

---

### Explanation:

```
dc -e '
# macro for quitting
[q]sq

# macro to read next line and perform operations
[
   ? z1=q  # read next line and quit when it is empty. The 1 is apriori
   r       # else, reverse the stack elements so that sum is top of stack now
   d1<q    # quit if current sum is more than 1
   r       # else, reverse the stack elements so that line is top of stack now
   n 32an p # print the line, space (32a is ascii decimal for space), & print current sum
   0.005+   # update the current sum for next round
   dd=?     # recursively invoke itself for more.... its a loop essentially
]s?

# initialize stack and start operations
0 l?x
'
```